# Shiny: keeping rows of data.table not in next session

Tags: r, shiny, data.table, rbind

working on an app I came to one(of many) little things, I have trouble with.

I have the user fill in `textInputs` in a `conditionalPanel` and after clicking the `actionButton` another conditionalPanel, that includes the same information in form of a `data.table` , comes up.

My problem seems to be the `rbind` function in combination with the `assignment operator`. I I don't use it, the table(Panel2) will only include the first row of the User Input from Panel1. If I use rbind, it does return the table I exspect (multiple input rows lead to multiple rows in the data. table).

But after closing and restarting my app, rbind is adding the new input to the old one.

Let's say my first input would be:

`A B C`

after closing and restarting I type in:

`D E F`

and the result would be

`A B C`

`D E F`
but I only want: `D E F` to be in my table.

Please have a look at my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(data.table)

ui = fluidPage( 
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.createTemplTable%2 == 0",
    actionButton("add", "Add new Row", icon=icon("plus", class=NULL, lib="font-awesome")),
    actionButton("remove", "Remove last Row", icon=icon("times", class = NULL, lib = "font-awesome")),
    fluidRow(
      column(2,
             textInput("first", label = h5("first"))
      ),
      column(2,
             textInput("second", label = h5("second"))
      ),
      column(2,
             textInput("third", label = h5("third"))
      )
    ), 
    tags$div(id = 'placeholder'),
    actionButton("createTemplTable", "Create Template")
  ),

  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.createTemplTable%2 == 1",
    #actionButton("return", "Return to Template Generator"),
    dataTableOutput("createdTempl")

  )
)

server = function(input, output) {

  ## keep track of elements inserted and not yet removed
  inserted <- reactiveValues(val = 0)
  tableColumns <- c("first", "second", "third")

  observeEvent(input$add, {
    id <- length(inserted$val) + 1
    insertUI(
      selector = "#placeholder",
      where = "beforeBegin",
      ui =tags$div(
        id = id,
        fluidRow(
          column(2,
                 textInput("first", label = (""))
          ),
          column(2,
                 textInput("second", label = (""))
          ),
          column(2,
                 textInput("third", label = (""))
          )

        ) 
      )
    )
    inserted$val <- c(inserted$val, id)

  })

  observeEvent(input$remove,{
    print(inserted$val)
    removeUI(
      selector = paste0('#', inserted$val[length(inserted$val)])
    )

    inserted$val <- inserted$val[-length(inserted$val)]
  })

  saveData <- function(data) {
    data <- as.data.table(t(data))
    if (exists("createdTempl")) {
       createdTempl <<- rbind(createdTempl, data)
     } else {
      createdTempl <<- data
    }
  }

  loadData <- function() {
    if (exists("createdTempl")) {
      createdTempl
    }
  }

  formData <- reactive({
    data <- sapply(tableColumns, function(x) input[[x]])
    data
  })

  observeEvent(input$createTemplTable, {
    saveData(formData())
  })

  output$createdTempl <- renderDataTable({
    input$createTemplTable
    loadData()  

  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Do I need to use session? If yes, how would I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: This is happening because variable `createdTempl` is a global variable which is shared across sessions. You should use reactive values instead.

Comment: How can a table be a reactiveValue? There is no reactiveDataTable. Sorry, I am still pretty new to shiny .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, global variables is shared across sessions, due to this the previous data was being displayed even when you restarted the app. So, you need to eliminate the global variables using `reactiveValues`. Though the name is `reactiveValue` it is actually a reactive variable and like all the other variable in R we can store a dataframe in `reactiveValues`. In your case it would be something as shown below. I have just modified your server code to eliminate the use of global variable.

```
 server = function(input, output) {

      ## keep track of elements inserted and not yet removed
      inserted <- reactiveValues(val = 0)
      tableColumns <- c("first", "second", "third")

      #Reactive value to store the data frame 
      createdTempl <- reactiveValues(val = NULL)

      observeEvent(input$add, {
        id <- length(inserted$val) + 1
        insertUI(
          selector = "#placeholder",
          where = "beforeBegin",
          ui =tags$div(
            id = id,
            fluidRow(
              column(2,textInput("first", label = (""))
              ),
              column(2,
                     textInput("second", label = (""))
              ),
              column(2,
                     textInput("third", label = (""))
              )

            ) 
          )
        )
        inserted$val <- c(inserted$val, id)

      })

      observeEvent(input$remove,{
        print(inserted$val)
        removeUI(
          selector = paste0('#', inserted$val[length(inserted$val)])
        )

        inserted$val <- inserted$val[-length(inserted$val)]
      })

      saveData <- function(data) {
        data <- as.data.table(t(data))
        if (!is.null(createdTempl$val)) {
          createdTempl$val <- rbind(createdTempl$val, data)
        } else {
          createdTempl$val <- data
        }
      }

      loadData <- function() {
        if (!is.null(createdTempl$val)) {
          createdTempl$val
        }
      }

      formData <- reactive({
        data <- sapply(tableColumns, function(x) input[[x]])
        data
      })

      observeEvent(input$createTemplTable, {
        saveData(formData())
      })

      output$createdTempl <- renderDataTable({
        input$createTemplTable
        loadData()  

      })

    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Now, no matter if I use `<<-` or `<-`  the table on the 2. page never shows more than 1 row. Am I missing something?

Comment: I guess that is because you are creating multiple `textInput` with the same `inputId`. Also, your `tableColumns` variable only has value for `textInput`, `first` `second` and `third` that you created initially.

Comment: I changed the `inputIds` in the server, so at least the second row should show up, right? It does not.

Comment: Have you modified your `tableColumns` variable?

Comment: You need to modify the `tableColumns` such that the new `inputId` are also included.

Comment: ok,, I did. however, it only now gives me the 2. row and the column names are not the ones I originally wanted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145612/discussion-between-rivka-and-sbista).

Answer (score 0):

With help of [SBista](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5894457/sbista) this is my final solution for this problem:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(data.table)

ui = fluidPage( 
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.createTemplTable%2 == 0",
    actionButton("add", "Add new Row", icon=icon("plus", class=NULL, lib="font-awesome")),
    actionButton("remove", "Remove last Row", icon=icon("times", class = NULL, lib = "font-awesome")),
    fluidRow(
      column(2,
             textInput("first", label = h5("first"))
      ),
      column(2,
             textInput("second", label = h5("second"))
      ),
      column(2,
             textInput("third", label = h5("third"))
      )
    ), 
    tags$div(id = 'placeholder'),
    actionButton("createTemplTable", "Create Template")
  ),

  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.createTemplTable%2 == 1",
    #actionButton("return", "Return to Template Generator"),
    dataTableOutput("createdTempl")

  )
)

server = function(input, output) {
  ## keep track of elements inserted and not yet removed
  inserted <- reactiveValues(val = 0)
  tableColumns <- c("first", "second", "third")

  #Reactive value to store the data
  createdTempl <- reactiveValues(val = NULL)
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    # browser()
    id <- length(inserted$val) + 1
    insertUI(
      selector = "#placeholder",
      where = "beforeBegin",
      ui =tags$div(
        id = id,
        fluidRow(
          column(2,textInput(paste0("first", id), label = (""))
          ),
          column(2,
                 textInput(paste0("second", id), label = (""))
          ),
          column(2,
                 textInput(paste0("third", id), label = (""))
          )

        ) 
      )
    )
    inserted$val <- c(inserted$val, id)

  })

  observeEvent(input$remove,{
    print(inserted$val)
    removeUI(
      selector = paste0('#', inserted$val[length(inserted$val)])
    )

    inserted$val <- inserted$val[-length(inserted$val)]
  })

  saveData <- function(data) {
    data <- as.data.table(t(data))
    if (!is.null(createdTempl$val)) {
      browser()
      createdTempl$val <- rbind(createdTempl$val, data)
    } else {
      createdTempl$val <- data
    }
  }

  loadData <- function() {
    if (!is.null(createdTempl$val)) {
      createdTempl$val
    }
  }

  formData <- reactive({
    # browser()
    if(length(inserted$val) >1){
      tabColNew <- sapply(inserted$val[2:length(inserted$val)], function(i){ c(paste0("first", i), paste0("second", i), paste0("third", i))})
      tableColumns <- rbind(tableColumns, t(tabColNew))
      data <- apply(tableColumns, 1, function(x){
        sapply(x, function(x)input[[x]])
      })
    }else{

      data <- sapply(tableColumns, function(x)input[[x]])
    }

    data
  })

  observeEvent(input$createTemplTable, {
    saveData(formData())
  })

  output$createdTempl <- renderDataTable({
    input$createTemplTable
    loadData()  

  })

}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```